# Showing that the right and left regular representations are equivalent

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group. Let $C(G,\mathbb{C})$ be the complex vector space of  all functions from $G$ to $\mathbb{C}$. We define two representations of G on $C(G,\mathbb{C})$: the left regular representation $\ell$ given by $(\ell(g)f)(x)=f(g^{-1}x)$ an the right regular representations $r$ given by $(r(g)f)(x)=f(xg)$. I try to show that the are equivalent. So we need to find an invertible intertwining operator $A$ such that $A\ell(g)=r(g)A$ for all $g\in G$. My book says $(Af)(x)=f(x^{-1})$ works and it is really easy to check that it really works. But I want to find the equation $(Af)(x)=f(x^{-1})$ explicitly.

Attempt: We need to find $A$ such that for any $f\in C(G,\mathbb{C})$ , $$(A\ell(g))(f)=(r(g)A)(f)$$ i.e. $\big((A\ell(g))(f)\big)(x)=\big((r(g)A)(f)\big)(x)$ for all $x\in G$

But $$\big((r(g)A)(f)\big)(x)=r(g)\big((Af)(x)\big)=(Af)(xg)$$
Similarly $$\big((A\ell(g))(f)\big)(x)=(Af)(g^{-1}x)$$

So the equality $(Af)(x)=f(x^{-1})$ given by the book does not imply $(Af)(xg)=(Af)(g^{-1}x)$. I couldn't see my mistake. Can anyone help? And how can we find the equality $(Af)(x)=f(x^{-1})$ for all $x\in G$? Thanks.

Comment: A basis for $C(G,\mathbb{C})$ is $\left\{\delta_g:g\in G\right\}$, where $\delta_g$ is the indicator function of $g$. Note $l(g)(\delta_h) = \delta_{gh}$ and $r(g)(\delta_h) = \delta_{hg^{-1}}$, so the two representations have the same character $$\chi(g) = \#\left\{h\in G:gh = h\right\} = \begin{cases}|G|\text{ if }g=1,\\ 0\text{ if not.}\end{cases}$$ and are therefore isomorphic.

Comment: Your mistake seems to be that you write $(A l(g)(f)) (x) = (Af)(g^{-1}x)$ which is not true.

Comment: Well, your 'similarly' argument does not work. It is true that you have $(l(g) A f)(x) = (Af)(g^{-1}x)$ but in general $l(g) A$ and $A l(g)$ will not coincide, especially not if you want $A l(g) = r(g) A$.

Comment: Thanks, now I couldn't see how I find $A$ because still I do not know what $\big((A\ell(g))(f)\big)(x)$ is.

Comment: But you realize that just from demanding that $A$ is an invertible intertwining operator, you will not be able to conclude $(Af)(x) = f(x^{-1})$? I mean, in general there are many other invertible intertwining operators.

Answer (score 0):

Mistake can be traced to the second equality in "But":

$$[r(g)Af] (x) = [r(g)f] (x^{-1}) = f(x^{-1}g),$$

i.e. you have implicitly assumed $r(g)A = Ar(g)$, hence your error.

For completeness, here is the calculation for the left regular repr:

$$[Al(g)f] (x) = [Af] (g^{-1}x) = f((g^{-1}x)^{-1}) = f(x^{-1}g).$$

**Aside:** I was also trying to check **unitary** equivalence of $(L,L^2(K))$ and $(R,L^2(K))$, where the group $G=K$ is now compact and the repr space is $L^2(K)$. Since $K$ is compact, the modular function $\Delta$ is identically $1$, and so the operator $A$, now viewed as an operator on $L^2(K)$, is unitary.